# Sequence proof on absolute value

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

So have to prove if $| a_n|\to0$, then $a_k\to0$ given that $a_k$ is a sequence.

I was wodnering how I might prove this, I considered that whats inside the absolute value must be positive and expanding it out, but got nowhere.

Comment: Just note that $| a_n | = | a_n - 0|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the $\epsilon$-definition of the limit, you have that

$$\forall\epsilon >0:\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}:||a_n|-0|<\epsilon\text{ for all }n\geq n_0$$

i.e., as $||a_n|-0|=||a_n||=|a_n|=|a_n-0|$, you have that

$$\forall\epsilon >0:\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}:|a_n-0|<\epsilon\text{ for all }n\geq n_0$$

which is per definition $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: What's the difference between the $\epsilon$-definition of the limit and the definition of the limit?

Comment: This almost went unnoticed by me, I think I just wanted to emphasize the chosen variant of stating the limit in this case, e.g. in difference to the definition in the context of topological spaces using neighborhoods(which is here equivalent, needless to say).

Comment: thanks! is f.a mean for all?

Comment: Yes.  I've edited my answer, as to not cause confusion in the future.